# Build a stack of segmented views

Tags: swift, swiftui, carekit

I was looking at the official Apple Healthcare documentation, when I noticed that they have a really nice UI design that I've also seen in other apps. I attached the photo to this post.[image: the image]

As you can see, on the left, they have a stack of organized almost cards with titles and coloration. Is there a SwiftUI framework to display a stack such as this, or would I have to custom design a view to display each little piece? Is this a list view?

Comment: Just put some buttons in a `VStack`. For the gradient try `.background(LinearGradient...)`

Comment: So these are just buttons with specialized labels?

Comment: Yep, seems like it